# Call a Function When Removing an Entity - Delete File

Tags: c#, entity-framework

## Problem Statement:

I've got the models set up with a one to many as follows:

```
public class ArticleHeading
{
    [Key]
    public int ArticleHeadingID

    public string ArticleHeadingName {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles {get;set;}

}

public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int ArticleID {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string ArticleContent {get;set;}

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("ArticleHeadingID")]
    public virtual ArticleHeading Heading {get;set;}
    
    [Required]
    public int ArticleHeadingID {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string ArticleImagePath {get;set;}
}
```

***Note: Some data members omitted because it is not relevant.***

What I want to achieve is that when I delete an

```
ArticleHeading
```

I want to also remove the images with this path:

```
ArticleImagePath
```

So the following code:

```
_context.ArticleHeadings.Remove(someArticleHeading);
```

Deletes all the Articles connected to it successfully, but I need to delete the images located at the paths inside the articles.

I could manually iterate through the articles easily, but I want to know if it is possible to override or extend that remove method so that I don't have to do it multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd want to create a layered architecture and take care of those concerns at the service or repository layer. The best way to do this without making those layers is to override the SaveChanges method in your Context class. Something like the following should get you going in the right direction.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var deletedArticleHeadings = ChangeTracker.Entries<ArticleHeading>().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList();

    foreach (var headingEntry in deletedArticleHeadings)
    {
        var heading = headingEntry.Entity;

        // Delete things.
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: So maybe I create a static method that takes the articleheading as argument and then does the relevant deletes? Obviously EF takes care of the foreign keys. Just those files that need to be removed. By the way - it is a good answer with useful code. Upvoted. Holding out answer to see if I can get some more tips!

Comment: Normally I set up my applications to have multiple layers. So a "front-end" or view layer, a controller layer, a service layer, and a data layer. The EF context normally acts as the data layer. So my controllers call a method in the service layer to "do things". So deleting an article heading occurs through a single method in a single class of your service layer. That method grabs all of the articles for the header, deletes them, deletes the actual article header and articles through the data layer, and any other things that need to occur on a delete.

Comment: I see. So I need an extra layer to these kinds of things. Thank you guys for the help.